# I am getting an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I believe title explains it all. Here is my code:

```
public String encrypt(String a) {

    char regex[] = a.toCharArray();
    char ans[] = {'E'};
    int anspointer = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < regex.length; i+=2){
        ans[anspointer] = regex[i];
        anspointer++;
        int b = r.nextInt(alpha.length-1);
        System.out.println("random number b="+b + " Contains:" + alpha[b]);
        ans[anspointer] = alpha[b];
        anspointer++;
        int c = r.nextInt(alpha.length-1);
        System.out.println("random number c="+c + " Contains:" + alpha[c]);
        ans[anspointer] = alpha[c];
        anspointer++;
    }
    return ans.toString();
}
```

And programs output.

```
    alpha size: 58
Encrypting: ASDF1234
random number b=16 Contains:Q
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at sec.encrypt(sec.java:39)
    at sec.main(sec.java:56)
```

The line 39 in encrypt method is:

```
System.out.println("random number b="+b + " Contains:" + alpha[b]);
```

Which is weird considering the fact that it produces an output.

Alpha list:

```
public final char[] alpha = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',
        'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
        'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a',
        'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
        'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
```

r value `Random r = new Random();`
Cheers :)

Comment: The easiest way to find out what is going on is to use the debugger in your IDE.

Comment: The code you posted won't even compile.  Where is "r" defined?  Learn how to use a debugger.  We are not human debuggers. Cheers :)

Comment: `ans` has only one element while you are keeping to add one to `anspointer`. That's out of bounds for sure.

Comment: The thing is that I tried to use a debugger and the results don't fit because everything seems to be correct, which is weird. That is why I decided to ask here.

Comment: Btw thanks to all for `-` -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of size 1:

```
char ans[] = {'E'};
```

But you are trying to access locations that does not exist using

```
ans[anspointer] = regex[i];
anspointer++;
```

Arrays have fixed sizes. Specify the size or use some kind of list e.g

```
char ans[] = new char[regex.length];
for(int i = 0; i < regex.length; i++){
    ans[anspointer] = regex[i];
    anspointer++;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array `ans` is only sized for one character. The second character causes your Exception. You should use a dynamically sized Collection, like [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) - like so,

```
List<Character> ans = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`ans` has a size of one. So `ans[anspointer] = alpha[b];` is the source of your exception once anspointer grows larger than 0 (which is pretty early on).